# Setting up remote access on a kobuki with a Hokuyo UST-10LX laser

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect to a Raspberry pi with Ubuntu Mate that I use to control the Kobuki, with my laptop for remote access.

I set up the necessary static IPs and set up the necessary ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI settings.However, since my Hokuyo laser is connected using Ethernet, the Ethernet connection seems to be getting the preference and the wifi network and internet becomes unusable on the Raspberry.

Is there a way i can circumvent this? Or am I missing something other than the ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI settings on both the PCs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320737/setting-up-remote-access-on-a-kobuki-with-a-hokuyo-ust-10lx-laser/) by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the routing table on the Raspberry pi OS.
For an example, let's say the **Hokuyo** is connected via **eth0** with IP address 10.0.0.5/24 and the IP address of the **Raspberri Pi** is 10.0.0.4/24. ROS communication happens via wlan0 where the IP address  of the **remote PC** is 192.168.0.5/24 and the IP address of the **Raspberri Pi** is something like 192.168.0.4/24, then you need to setup the routing table as follows.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.5 dev wlan0

sudo ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.5 dev eth0
```

You can check if the routing table is configured properly using `ip route show` command.

After setting the routing table, you can confirm that it's configured properly by pinging `10.0.0.5` and `192.168.0.5` **from** Raspberri Pi.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on 2019-04-10**:
Thanks a lot! This was just what I needed.